# How to configure AVD Android Studio?

Tags: android, mobile, sdk, emulation, android-virtual-device

I am setting up the AVD for my emulator on Android Studio and trying to get it to mimic the phone I have; it is a Samsung Galaxy s4.

Under the "Select Hardware" section are only a few names, none of which match my phone. Am I supposed to choose this part based off the screen size and resolution alone?

The next section has me select the "System Image." My device is version 4.3, but there are two download options for that: x86 and ameabi-v7a. Which do I get and what exactly do these terms mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Samsung Galaxy S4 is not a part of the standard AVD, you will have to create it. What you should be doing:-

1. Name your device as your "Galaxy S4".
2. Select your screen resolution and memory after looking it up on the internet.
3. I suggest you download an x86 image with the HAX accelerator driver from the SDK manager. This will make your virtual device run faster. If you get the ameabi-v7a, your virtual device will be slow due to the virtualisation overhead for your CPU.
4. Run your AVD, make sure you have enough RAM for your host OS. I would recommend about 8GB as optimal.

To be clear x86 and ameabi-v7 refer to the cpu architectures of the regular 32 bit PCs and the ARM processors respectively.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, not all physical Android phone model is built in AVD.

secondly, you can use the command bellow to get your Android device ABI, which indicates CPU types(e.g. x86) in use:

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi
```